# put some hex string to xxd using stdin does not generate any output

Tags: linux, shell, sh, dd, xxd

I have a problem with gathering data by xxd from stdin. Here is the command:

```
xxd -r -p | dd of=/home/user/test/hex.bin obs=16
```

when I execute this command in shell, then it waits for input. I tried to put '0006303030304e430006303030304e43' then press enter, but it looks like xxd did not get my input or did not piped output to dd.

For instance, this works perfectly:

```
echo '0006303030304e430006303030304e43' | xxd -r -p | dd of=/home/user/test/hex.bin obs=16
```

What I want to achieve:
I want to put some hex string, convert it to binary and then save to file in 16 bit chunk. The script must listen on stdin constantly.

Does xxd work this way? I tried to put \n or \r\n at the end of the hex string, but still nothing was on the xxd output.

Thanks for any help.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

`xxd` is still waiting for input; type Control-D after you hit enter to "close" the input file.

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to terminate the command. I want to do it like this

stdin (hex string) -> xxd (binary) -> dd -> myfile.bin -> stdin... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Just append `-` to `xxd -r -p` command, such that it looks like this:

```
echo '0006303030304e430006303030304e43' | xxd -r -p - | dd of=/home/user/test/hex.bin obs=16
```

I found this in the man page for `xxd`; more specifically, the `OPTIONS` section:

> If *infile* is specified as a `-` character, then input is taken from standard input.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't terminate standard input with Ctl-D you need to feed it until buffers fill in the pipe bewfore anything moves along to the next process.  In the end you will still have to enter Ctl-D or it will never terminate.

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.